# Is it still possible to go jogging around the Panathenaic Stadium in Athens?

Tags: activities, athens, sport

The [Panathenaic Stadium website](http://www.panathenaicstadium.gr/Visit/tabid/87/language/en-US/Default.aspx) suggests that it is possible to run in the stadium between 7.30 and 9 am, but the site is old (2011) and the form that must be filled in (linked to from the web page) is no longer available online. If I just turn up in my running clothes (with a biro and the entrance fee) will I be allowed to run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is still possible, but apparently not that popular. You just turn up, pay the entrance fee for the stadium and museum (€10 in April 2023) and sign the form they give you (biro provided).